# Decomposing Square Matrix Into Two Matrices Which Are Transposes of Each Other

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Let $X$ be a real-valued square $n \times n$ matrix.

Is there decomposition $X = \Lambda \Lambda^\top$ where $\Lambda$ is a a real-valued $n \times k$ matrix, that always exists?

Comment: $\Lambda \Lambda^\top$ is always symmetric.

Comment: ..and positive semi-definite

Comment: Oh of course, Thanks!

Comment: Interestingly, if $X$ is complex and symmetric, then there exists a complex $\Lambda$ so that $X = \Lambda \Lambda^T$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every real symmetric matrix can be written in the form

$$ X = Q D Q^T $$

where $Q$ is formed from an orthonormal set of eigenvectors of $X$ and the diagonal of $D$ contains the corresponding eigenvalues. If the eigenvalues are non-negative, then the real matrix $\Lambda = PD^{1/2}$ satisfies your condition.

$$ X = (PD^{1/2})(D^{1/2}P^T) = \Lambda \Lambda^T $$

Note that all matrices formed by the product $ \Lambda \Lambda^T $ are positive semidefinite, so the following statements are equivalent:

1. $X$ is a real positive semidefinite matrix.
2. There exists a real matrix $\Lambda$ such that $X = \Lambda \Lambda^T$.

Answer (score 2):

If $X \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times m}$ is positive definite and hermitian then there exists the Cholesky decomposition such that

$$ X = R^{*}R$$

where

$$ X = \underbrace{R_{1}^{*}R_{2}^{*} \cdots R_{m}^{*} }_{R^{*}}\underbrace{R_{m} \cdots R_{2} R_{1}}_{R}$$

with 
$$ X = R^{*}R ,  r_{jj} > 0 $$
which can be done as

[image]